# Unity transform.position not working properly

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

**Okay so I figured out the issue I was having. The location that was being returned for the portal was inside the portal and it would glitch out when one object was inside another, so I just added an empty object to the portal where I want them to exit and had the program point to that.**

I am working on a little "game" in Unity and there are four portals labeled, `PortalMain1`, `PortalMain2`, `PortalMain3`, and `PortalMain4` and the goal would be for the player to be able to run into the collider on each on of the portals and be randomly teleported to one of the other portals.

I have this bit of code on the player model handling the trigger events:

```
private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
{
    int PortalDestination = Random.Range(1, 4);  ///Portals index at 1 because Unity
    string Portal = "PortalMain" + PortalDestination;
    Debug.Log(Portal);
    transform.position = GameObject.Find(Portal).transform.position;
}
```

What actually happens in the game is when the player collides with the box collider on the portal the game will properly choose a portal from 1-4 (although, it seems to never choose the one you touch  which is neat) and teleport you there.

Except you get teleported near the portal instead of on top of it, and that's if the teleportation does work it seems to only work about 1/4 the time.

Here is a picture of the hierarchy of the scene with the base:

[image: scene with the base]

Here is a picture of the hierarchy of the scene with the building:

[image: scene with the building]

Here is a picture of the hierarchy of the scene with the portal:

[image: scene with the portal]

EDIT #1: I reworked my method to work with `Rigidbody`, but the problem persists.

```
private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
{
    int PortalDestination = Random.Range(1, 4);  ///Portals index at 1 because Unity
    string Portal = "PortalMain" + PortalDestination;
    Debug.Log(Portal);
    GetComponent<Rigidbody>().isKinematic = true;
    GetComponent<Rigidbody>().position = GameObject.Find(Portal).transform.position;
    GetComponent<Rigidbody>().isKinematic = false;
}
```

Here is the Github link > https://github.com/LvInSaNevL/Bamboozle

Comment: As it was said many times now, do not use translation when dealing with physics. Use `Rigidbody` to benefit physics engine functionality

Comment: @m.rogalski the only way I have found would be to physically move the rigidbody with a vector. I want more of an "instant" teleportation. Is that possible? I tried `GetComponent<Rigidbody>().position = GameObject.Find(Portal).transform.position;` as per the documentation and that only works about 25% of the time.

Comment: Can you post a picture of your hierarchy, specifically of a portal object. Also a picture of your portal in scene view - While selected - would be helpful. And for instant teleportation, i find that using transform.position to work just fine!

Comment: Also your latest edit doesnt alter anything. <Rigidbody>().position is exactly the same as .position.

Comment: @Immorality there is now a picture added.

Comment: @Immorality I believe he was trying to follow @m.rogalski's advice to use `RigidBody` instead of translation.

Comment: Could you also provide a picture while having the portal's parent selected, and a picture having the portal's child selected?

Comment: The portals parent is just the building it's sitting on and the buildings parent is the base. It goes /base/buildingX/PortalY/.

Comment: Yes but i would love to see the settings of the components. Could it be that one of them is a colider and not a trigger? this could make your character "jump" out of the colider and thus give your the wrong location.

Comment: @Immorality I added the pictures but the only collider that is set as a trigger is the box collider on the portal.

Comment: I believe this may be because of not using the Y axis as up. Im afraid i can help you no more on this

Comment: @Immorality Y is up in the scene

Comment: Maybe try looking at this video to see how this guy does it. [Brackeys](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cuQao3hEKfs)

Comment: You're using `OnTriggerEnter` method but from what you've posted there's no object with `IsTrigger` flag set. Can you confirm that at least one of your object has that flag set when colliding?

Answer (score 0):

For first, attach OnTriggerEnter to the TRIGGER, not a player.

For second, attach this script on portal and set spawnPoint explicitly.

After that you can copy that portal anywhere you want, and it will add itself to list of possible portals for player to exit.

```
public class Portal : MonoBehaviour {
    public static List<Portal> portals {get; protected set;}
    public Transform spawnPoint; // Set it in the editor
    protected bool ignoreNextTouches = false;

    private void Start () {
        if (portals == null)
            portals = new List<Portal>();
        portals.Add (this);
    }
    private void OnTriggerEnter (Collider other) {
        if (!other.gameObject.tag.Equals ("Player"))
            return;
        if (ignoreNextTouches) {
            ignoreNextTouches = false;
            return;
        }
        Portal random = GetRandomPortal (this);
        random.ignoreNextTouches = true;
        other.transform.position = random.spawnPoint.position;
    }
    private static Portal GetRandomPortal (Portal exceptThis) {
        Portal  p = exceptThis;
        while (p == exceptThis)
            p = portals[Random.Range(0,portals.Length)];
        return p;
    }
}
```